# Computing mean of points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a polygon and inside it are points with z-values. I want to get the mean of the z-values within the polygon.

How can I do that in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Z value is part of the geometry (so the featureclass is a PointZ) or that they are attributes of the points (the Z value is in a field)?

Comment: The Z is the attribute.

Comment: Select by Location - Summary statistics

Comment: But I want the output as shp as well.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the mean z-values of all points in a polygon as an attribute to the polygon?

Comment: Yes, that is what I see as output

Answer (score 4):

You can use arcpy with the da.SearchCursor. If the Z value is stored in the geometry use the `SHAPE@Z` token. Select the Points by the polygon then execute this in the python window:

```py
import arcpy

pointlayer = 'Points' #Change
pointlist = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointlayer,'SHAPE@Z') if i[0] is not None]

print sum(pointlist)/len(pointlist)
```

If they are stored in a field, change 'SHAPE@Z' to the name of your field.